# Is the poetic phrase "Time stumbled and fell" considered a Juxtaposition?

Tags: poetry, literature

In the poem "People on the Bridge" written by Wislawa Szymborksa (Translated by Joanna Trzceiak) the phrase "Time stumbled and fell" is used. Is this an example of a juxtaposition used by the poet?

Comment: Juxtaposition of *what*?

Comment: *Metaphorical* juxtapostion of ***Time*** as an *abstract concept* (the way we normally understand it), and ***Time "personified"*** (as in "Old Father Time", seen as *an actual person*, who could stop moving and/or lose "his" footing). But as @Robusto implies, we wouldn't normally label that device as "juxtaposition". It's just a "metaphor".

Comment: "Stumbled and fell" is a common juxtaposition used when describing, eg, how someone tripped over something.  In "time stumbled and fell" it is used as a metaphor, but there's nothing remarkable about the "juxtaposition".

Comment: I see your question was closed here. Feel free to re-ask it on [literature.se], where we take questions about poetry and the literary devices like juxtaposition used therein. There are a couple of Literature users who I'm sure could write a good answer for this question, more detailed than the one you received here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Chambers online defines *juxtaposition* as

> placing or being placed together.

Lexico goes a bit further and provides the definition

> The fact of two things being seen or placed close together with
>   contrasting effect.

I don't see any of that in the sentence you give us.  Perhaps you are searching for the word *metaphor* which is probably a fair description of the idea of time stumbling as if it were a legged animal rather than, well, something rather more abstract.